Как работает свойство mix-blend-mode: difference?
Почему mix-blend-mode:difference меняет белый цвет текста на чёрный цвет, когда белый фон. А когда чёрный цвет текста на чёрном фоне, то не меняет текст на белый цвет.
Белый текст на белом фоне. Происходит инверсия белого цвета в чёрный.


.btn {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
<button class="btn">
  <span class="text">Click me</span>
</button>



Чёрный текст на чёрном фоне. Никакой инверсии не происходит.


.btn {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
  color: black;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
<button class="btn">
  <span class="text">Click me</span>
</button>




а почему должна происходить инверсия? значение difference, а не какой-нибудь inversion. Надо просто посмотреть что из чего вычитается

difference - вычитание. на мониторе пиксель красится RGB палитрой(обычно) от исходно черного(#00 00 00) до белого(#FF FF FF). если из черного(нулей) вычесть черный(ноль) то и получим ноль. пощупать разные режимы можно тут
